# What's the meaning of 'pat on the back'?

Tags: meaning

I am reading a blog post: https://www.trustgreene.com/blog/2019/4/5/i-am-nobody-and-so-are-you

The article has this paragraph.

> I am nobody. But that doesn’t mean I am not somebody. Or does it?
>
> I lost my mom when I was 20. My dad when I was 33. I wasn’t the first
>   person this happened to and I won’t be the last. I once pissed my
>   pants in 8th grade. Again, *pat on the back*.

The 'pat on the back' has the meaning of praise. (https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/137962/116378)

But I think the meaning doesn't fit with the context as he pissed his pants and that's not a good thing to be praised at all. What is the meaning of 'pat on the back' in this paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same meaning, he's just being sarcastic/ironic.  It's used in the same sense as the previous paragraph uses "Big deal" to describe something (somebody being born in NYC) which is clearly very commonplace and therefore not a big deal.  Or if I were to say, for example, "I went to the shops today, for such a great accomplishment I deserve a medal."